# Render the Django REST Framework uploading system with an HTML script

Tags: python, html, django, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework

I have developed a simple file-upload system using Django REST Framework using this tutorial [How to upload files to AWS S3 with Django](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-upload-files-to-aws-s3-using-django-rest-framework/). Basically the system allows user to upload files to an AWS S3 bucket.
This is what the users currently see:

[image: Django REST Framework uploader]

This is the following django project structure:

```css
DROPBOXER-MASTER
|
|--- dropboxer
     |
     |--- settings.py
     |--- urls.py
     |--- wsgi.py
|--- uploader
     |
     |--- views.py
     |--- urls.py
     |--- serializers.py
     |--- models.py
     |--- apps.py
|--- templates
     |--- index.html
|--- manage.py
|--- requirements.txt
```

This is the dropboxer/urls.py:

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include  # new

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('rest_framework.urls')),  # new
    path('', include('uploader.urls')),  # new
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

This is the dropboxer/settings.py:

```py
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '*****************************************'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # 3rd party apps
    'rest_framework',

    # local apps
    'uploader',  # new
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'dropboxer.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR, 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'dropboxer.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '******************'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '******************'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = '******************'
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = 's3v4'
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = '********'
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
# AWS_S3_VERIFY = True
AWS_S3_VERIFY = False
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

This is the uploader/urls.py:

```py
from rest_framework.routers import SimpleRouter, DefaultRouter

from .views import DropBoxViewset

router = SimpleRouter()

router.register('', DropBoxViewset)

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

This is the uploader/views.py file:

```js
from rest_framework import viewsets, parsers

from .models import DropBox
from .serializers import DropBoxSerializer


class DropBoxViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = DropBox.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DropBoxSerializer
    parser_classes = [parsers.MultiPartParser, parsers.FormParser]
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'patch', 'delete']


from django.shortcuts import render

def upload_page(request):

    # Render the bindex.html template
    return render(request, "index.html")
```

This is the uploader/models.py file:

```py
from django.db import models

class DropBox(models.Model):

    '''A simple model for uploading files.'''
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    document = models.FileField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Drop Boxes'
```

And finally this is the templates/indexer.html:

```html
<form action="{% url 'dropbox-list' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
  </form>
```

Now, when I run the project with the command `python manage.py runserver` what I see is the UI that I showed before and not the indexer.html that I expect, which should be this:

[image: indexer.html]

Do you know where is the mistake?

Comment: Where have you mapped a URL to that template?

Comment: In the views.py script under the upload_page function right?

Comment: That's where you USE the template, but who is going to call `upload_page`?